# Inner Join returns all record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a three tables

1. tblVegetationClass (VegetationClassID is a column Name)
2. tblVegTypeVegFormationLink
3. tblVegetationType

I have the following query

```
SELECT   dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeCode,  
    dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeName,dbo.tblVegetationClass.VegetationClassID,
    dbo.tblVegTypeVegFormationLink.VegetationFormationID
FROM dbo.tblVegetationType 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblVegTypeVegFormationLink
    ON dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeID = dbo.tblVegTypeVegFormationLink.VegTypeID
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblVegetationClass
    ON dbo.tblVegetationType.VegetationClassID=dbo.tblVegetationClass.VegetationClassID
    INNER JOIN tblCMAVegTypeLink 
    ON dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeID = dbo.tblCMAVegTypeLink.VegTypeID
WHERE   dbo.tblVegetationType.PercentageCleared >= 50 
    AND dbo.tblVegTypeVegFormationLink.VegetationFormationID = 313
    AND dbo.tblCMAVegTypeLink.CMAID = 4 
    AND (dbo.tblVegetationType.EffectiveDateTo IS NULL)
```

The query returns

```
VegTypeCode VegTypeName VegetationClassID   VegetationFormationID
HU532       Coastal     40                   313
HU591       Paperbark   39                   313
HU633       Swamp       39                   313
HU635       Swamp       40                   313
```

[image]

I am expecting the query only returns record 2 and 3 or 1 and 4.

> Inner join is not matching the
>   tblVegetationType.VegetationClassID=tblVegetetationClass.VegetationClassID

Can you please correct me what i did wrong in my query ?

Answer (score 2):

Your WHERE clause does not constrain `tblVegetationClass` in any way, so it will allow all such records through.  If you were to add

```
AND dbo.tblVegetationClass.ID = 1
```

(or something along those lines) you would be restricting which vegetation class was returned by the query.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve all the VegTypeName and Code that belongs to VegetationClassID and VegatationFormationID

Comment: tblVegetationClass.ID is a primary Key in that table ,i am using FK in tblVegtationType

Comment: Your question says, "I am expecting the query only returns record 2 and 3 or 1 and 4."  Why do you expect that?

Comment: coz , i am trying to retrieve the query will return VegTypeName and Code in the same VegetationClassID and FormationID

Comment: You need to take more care with your grammar.  I do not understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Oops Sorry, I understand now. I missed the VegetationClassID in the Where Clause as you mentioned before. I think i have to write a subquery to find out what's the VegClassID then retrieve the records based on that will solve my problem